# What sort of USB WiFi receiver will work through solid walls?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm looking for a USB wireless adapter that will work well through solid walls. Size and style are not important. Is there thing like USB+Antenna/Booster plugged in electric socket? Something like [this one].[2](http://uk.wifi-link.com/wifi-wlan-booster-antennas/)

Comment: What are the walls made out of?  802.11N is 801.11N you can have the most expensive adapter in the world, its still a radio signal, and it still does not like walls.

Comment: Firstly, please do watch your language. Secondly we don't normally do specific product recommendations here. Please clean up your question by pressing the edit button and you'll receive a decent number of answers.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Comment: You can do directional extension which may (citation/research needed) boost the signal as it is concentrating the signal to 1 direction rather than every direction. [WokFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WokFi) is one method. Have you considered making a small hole to run a LAN cable through? If the wall is truly solid, wifi signal can be completely blocked. Especially if inside the wall there are other cables running.

Answer (score 1):

A wireless routers radio signals reach out to about 100 feet in every direction. Everything blocks Wi-Fi signals a little. Wood, plaster, cinder blocks, and glass don't interfere much, but brick, stone, and water (think of that 30-gallon fish tank) can be more problematic. Worse still are ceramic, concrete, metal, and mirrors, which reflect visible light and radio waves alike.

So unless you live inside a bank vault, you will be just fine.

Comment: But, what about Booster is there some kind of booster/antenna connected with usb and electric socket, for example TV antenna, which is connected with TV and electric socket.

Comment: Many wireless routers, USB or not have support for signal boosters.

Comment: But what about additional very strong booster/amplifier, not those minimals?

Comment: Yes, you can add that type along with anything else you can imagine. You are only limited to what you can do by your own imagination.

https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+usb+wifi+boosters

Comment: Will it be better than integrated chip into the laptop?

Comment: That depends on the hardware, both internal and of the USB. USBs can be just as good.